# Get the stream object using stream_id in tokbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a stream object that I can pass on to a `forcemuteStream` method. I currently have the `stream_id`, does anyone knows how to do please? the `stream_id` is a `string`. My final method looks like below:

```
    session.forceMuteStream(stream)
        .catch(function() {
            alert("Mute Individual OK")
        }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    });
```